# Content of SKS not displayed

Tags: sprite-kit

maybe you can help me.

I have a main scene called GameScene.sks. In this scene I try to show a game over scene when the player lost the game. For this reason I created a GameOverScene.sks with a GameOver label and a Color Sprite Background Image.

To display the game over scene I use the following commands:

```
var secondScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
var transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(1.0)
secondScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
self.scene!.view?.presentScene(secondScene, transition: transition)
```

A scene is displayed but no Nodes that I defined in the sks are displayed. I don't know why, can you please help me? In Xcode Editor all Nodes of GameOverScene.sks are displayed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading the GameOverScene from the file, just initializing an empty object, it won't magically load just because it has the same name :)

To load it from the file use the unarchivefromFile: method provided as boilerplate code in a new sprite kit project.

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
var secondScene = GameOverScene.unarchiveFromFile("<sks file name here>") as GameOverScene
```

note: the size of the new scene will be whatever is set in the sks file (default: 1024x768) so you may need to change it to fit a device.

Also the init method with is called when you unarchive a scene is `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` in case you need to override it (remember to call `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` to ensure that your scene's contents are actually loaded from the file.

**Edit: To use this in your own scene**

in the scene you want to unarchive put:

```
override class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as ***YourSceneNameHere***
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

and replace `***YourSceneNameHere***` with e.g.: GameOverScene

**Edit: Explaination**

This method loads an SKScene from an sks file in your app's bundle. The steps it takes are:

1. Find the path to the sks file in your app's bundle if it exists.
2. Load the bytes in that file into an NSData object.
3. Initialize the Unarchiver, this will read the bytes in NSData and load+configure objects from it.
4. Tell the unarchiver to create instances of `***YourSceneName***` whenever it reads SKScene in the file.
5. Decode the data and cast the returned object to `***YourSceneName***`
6. Tell the archiver we are done reading the file data
7. Return the unarchived scene
8. If the sks file could not be found, return nil
   the method needs to be overridden so that `self.classForNSKeyedUnarchiver` returns the right class for your scene.

Comment: Thank you Okapi for your reply, but when I do it like you described I get the following error: "Swift dynamic cast failed"

Comment: Now it works, but can you explain me what happens here ? And why do we need to override it. Thank you :)